# (Modernes) Buch über die Syntax des Deutschen

Tags: reference-request

Ich bin auf der Suche nach einem Buch über die deutsche Syntax. Dank meiner universitären Studien kenne ich mich mit den Grundlagen der generativen Grammatik gut aus und hatte schon mit dependentiellen Theorien zu tun. Darum geht es aber erstmal nicht.

Wenige - denke ich - haben nie von der Idee gehört, dass L2-Lerner die deutsche Syntax als einen Behemoth-ähnlichen Haufen von grauenhaften Regeln wahrnehmen. Leider bin ich selbst L2-Lerner und muss sagen, dass ich nach fünf Jahren Deutschunterricht manchmal noch am Scheitern bin. In welche Reihenfolge stelle ich die Phrasen eines Satzes? Wie soll die Informationsstruktur in einem bestimmten Fall aussehen? Kann ich zehn Relativphrasen in einen Satz nacheinander einbetten, ohne dass derjenige, der meinen Aufsatz lesen wird, nach den ersten drei deswegen klagen wird?

Klar ist es, dass meine Bedenken nicht nur auf die Syntax bezogen sind. Trotzdem will ich euch fragen:

*Gibt es ein Buch, das Antworten auf manche meiner Fragen geben könnte?*

Comment: Ich fürchte, dass es schwierig sein wird, ein Buch zu finden, das die Regeln vollständig darstellt, ohne den L2-Lerner durch die Vielzahl von Regeln und Ausnahmen abzuschrecken. Ein gutes Lehrbuch für Deutsch als Fremdsprache wird sich zunächst auf die wichtigsten Regeln beschränken. Die Regeln vollständig aufzuführen, ohne die deutsche Sprache wie einen "Behemoth-ähnlichen Haufen von grauenhaften Regeln" aussehen zu lassen, ist wahrscheinlich eine nahezu unlösbare Aufgabe.

Comment: Als sprachwissenschaftlicher Neuling erschrecken mich Regeln in der Regel (Ha!) eigentlich nicht. Meine Frage bezog sich eher auf die Punkte der deutschen Syntax, die in "traditionellen" Kursen häufig vermieden oder nebenbei besprochen werden. Viel habe ich mich gefreut wenn die Lektorin für ungarische Sprache in der zweiten Woche des Sprachkurses die Informationsstruktur des Ungarischen (fókusz und all das) angesprochen hat. So etwas fehlt mir für Deutsch.

Answer (score 5):

Das Standardwerk zur Syntax der deutschen Sprache von Hans-Werner Eroms, das (oh Wunder!) "Syntax der deutschen Sprache" heißt, ist bei [Google Books](https://books.google.de/books?id=4FEDyiy-LO8C&pg=PA38&lpg=PA38&dq=syntax%20der%20deutschen%20sprache&source=bl&ots=tt8xxDWxxE&sig=NRV-Ob_N6IWJs426dMvrKSaRNTU&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwifmbSTktfUAhVE0xQKHTTMD3EQ6AEIdzAJ#v=onepage&q=syntax%20der%20deutschen%20sprache&f=false) in Auszügen verfügbar. Es ist 2001 erschienen und deshalb ausgesprochen aktuell (zumindestens nach Maßstäben für wissenschaftliche Arbeiten). Vielleicht möchtest du mal reinschnuppern, ob das etwas nach deinem Geschmack ist.

Solche Bücher sind möglicherweise sehr gut, um *zu verstehen, wieso* eine Sprache so funktioniert, wie sie es eben tut. Ob sie allerdings *zum Erlernen* der Sprache geeignet sind, bezweifle ich - Das erworbene Regelwissen in einem normalen Gespräch anzuwenden, halte ich für unmöglich. Du würdest 10 Minuten brauchen, um einen einzelnen Satz zu formulieren. Sprache lernt man am besten, indem man die Regeln so oft wie möglich praktisch anwendet (und sie wahrscheinlich nicht einmal kennt) - nicht, indem man sie auswendig lernt.

Comment: Vielen Dank für deinen Hinweis! Ich habe mir das Buch angeguckt und es scheint so, als ob es mir etwas helfen könnte. Was hier leider fehlt ist eine Besprechung der Schnittstelle Syntax/Semantik; hättest du weitere Empfehlungen in diese Richtung?